# Throwing checked exception as unchecked. Is there any way to prevent in runtime?

Tags: java, exception, checked, unchecked

With the simplified code I can throw Checked Exception without catching (the same way as uncheked). From javadoc about RuntimeException -
*Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions*. Is there any way to prevent the behavior in runtime?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestException {

    static <E extends Exception>

    void doThrow(final Exception e) throws E {
        throw (E) e;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestException.<RuntimeException>doThrow(
              new IOException("Checked exception thrown")
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the compiler warns you that you're potentially shooting yourself in the foot by doing such an unchecked cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, correct the method signature to:

```
static <E extends Exception> void doThrow(final E e) throws E {
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: +1 Of course I can correct the signature but the goal a little bit different. The approach allows programmer throwing checked exception as unchecked. The example just used to show how to suppress compile time problems.

Comment: So what *is* the goal? If goal is to allow programmers to throw unchecked exceptions, leave it as it is. If the goal is to stop them, fix it as above.

Comment: The goal is to prevent throwing Checked Exception as unchecked. Of course I can fix the signature but programmer can write own doThrow method like above to suppress the compile time only restriction.

Comment: @StanislavL the solution to protect your code against malicious coders is not technical. If you have developers doing that on purpose, you should have a serious conversation with them, and consider not letting touch the code anymore.

Comment: @StanislavL In that case I don't understand the question. What sort of a solution could possibly exist? If that's what the language allows, that's what the language allows.